# Nonlinear system of equation in real life

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

Good night (from my country) for all Mathematicians here. Last week my teacher gave me an indivudal assignment to do during the holidays. He asked us to provide either nonlinear or nonlinear system of ordinary differential equation in our daily lifes. He provided us one example, i.e. suspension system of quarter car model.
I was thinking that RLC circuit could be categorized as one of them. Am I wrong?. Could you help me to give some examples or build a logical thinking here?

Comment: RLC is not very non-linear. You need to add some diode or transistor to the circuit to get non-linearity. For example the ring modulator (used for the Dalek voices and other sound effects) has a ring of diodes.

Comment: thanks for your response, i will keep your answer :)